# D3 chart how to add arrow on each axis end

Tags: d3.js

How to add Arrow mark at end of the axis in d3 bar chat as shown in the below image
.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this attribute to your axis:

```
.attr("marker-end","url(#arrow)")
```

Resources:

- Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/marker-end
- Observable example: https://observablehq.com/@basilesimon/arrowheads-on-axes